# How to access local images in Electron app with Vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack, electron

I have an Electron app that uses Vue for its UI. The app downloads compressed data files from a server. The files contain compressed HTML. The app decompresses and display the HTML. That's all working fine.

The HTML may contain img tags that reference images that are also compressed in the downloaded file. I extract and decompress these images, but then need to a) put them somewhere that the app can see them, and b) construct an img tag that correctly references these images.

Rather than list the dozens of places I've tried to put these images, suffice to say that no matter where I put the images, I don't seem to be able to access them from the app. I get a 404 error, and usually a message saying the app can't reference local resources.

Any suggestions for where the app should store these images, and then how to reference them from img tags?

I have a related problem with images I could reference from the Web, but would prefer to download and cache locally so that the app can display them when there's no internet connection. I feel like if I can solve one of these problems, I can solve them both.

Comment: you may try something like [this](https://gist.github.com/ccnokes/95cb454860dbf8577e88d734c3f31e08#file-store-js), and the whole article [here](https://cameronnokes.com/blog/how-to-store-user-data-in-electron/)

Comment: @Bubai storing the data isn't the problem. I have a UserPreferences object that works a lot like the article describes, and I can download, store, and later read the compressed data files I mentioned in the question. The issue is figuring out where to put the images so that they can be referenced in an img tag and displayed.

Answer (score 0):

this below setting(s) works for me...

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── css
│   │   └── app.6cb8b97a.css
│   ├── img
│   │   └── icon.1ba2ae71.png
│   ├── index.html
│   └── js
│       ├── app.08f128b0.js
│       ├── app.08f128b0.js.map
│       ├── chunk-vendors.e396765f.js
│       └── chunk-vendors.e396765f.js.map
├── electron.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── index.html
└── src
    ├── App.vue
    ├── components
    │   ├── _breakpoint.scss
    │   └── RoundList.vue
    ├── img
    │   ├── bullet.svg
    │   └── icon.png
    └── index.js
```

vue.config.js:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "./basic_app/dist"),
  publicPath: './'
};
```

part of package.json

```json
"scripts": {
  "build:vue": "vue-cli-service build",
  "serve:electron": "electron .",
  "serve": "concurrently \"yarn build:vue\" \"yarn serve:electron\"",
  "build:electron": ""
},
```

the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKK7y.png

Comment: What happens if you use `https.request()` to read an image from your website, then use `fs.writeFileSync()` to write that image to a folder somewhere in your folder hierarchy. Can you then use JavaScript to insert an `<img>` tag into the DOM that references that image? If that works, where are you putting the saved image, and how do you reference it in the `src=` attribute of the `<img>` tag?